# SearchView drawables in ActionBar appear blurred

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have the following menu layout for my ActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/itemSearch"
        android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_icon_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" 
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

And here's the setup code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_default, menu);

    SearchView searchView=(SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.itemSearch).getActionView();
    int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    View searchEditText = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId); 
    ((TextView) searchEditText).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {...});
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {...});
}
```

Everything is ok, except for one thing: on my Asus tablet (TF-201, Android 3.2.1) graphics are blurred:

[image]

If I remove `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`, everything looks normal:

[image]

This problem is not reproduced on 4.1.2 emulator. I tried leaving only menu inflation code in my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` but that didn't help.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @TolgayToklar no, I did not. Does the accepted answer not work for you?

Comment: No it didn't. Then i resolved this by extending searchview from appcombat v7 class.

Comment: @TolgayToklar please feel free to post your solution as an answer. The accepted answer is probably outdated by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I beat up the solution, however, it declares right compatibility only for API 14 and above, if not using ActionBarSherlock library.

---

## First solution (API 14+)

Important is to be connected to **Themed Context** of application, otherwise you get lowest possible design for SearchView (blurry icons)

**Creating SearchView programmatically**

**FRAGMENT**

```
SearchView searchView =
                new SearchView(getActivity().getActionBar().getThemedContext());
```

**ACTIVITY**

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getActionBar().getThemedContext());
```

## Second solution (ABS compatibility, API 8+)

**ACTION BAR SHERLOCK FRAGMENT**

```
SearchView searchView = 
  new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
```

**ACTION BAR SHERLOCK ACTIVITY**

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
```

---

## Third solution (API 11+)

In some cases, setting `SearchView.setBackgroundColor(int color)` makes the icon appear less blurry, try **Color.WHITE** or **Color.BLACK**

***Note** that this changes background color for MenuItem whether collapsed or not, and eg. by using Theme Holo.Light.DarkActionBar you need to use right color, according to your ActionBar style.*

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same problem but other answer did not resolve my problem. I am extending my activity class from `AppCompatActivity`. My searchview icon was looking blurry on Android 4.* and it was looking good on Android 5.* without any problem.

I changed my xml to this:

```
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      android:iconifiedByDefault="true" />
```

And imported

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
```

Instead of `import android.widget.SearchView;`

And problem fixed.