# Strange SearchView behaviour

Tags: android

I originally had this working with ActionBarSherlock but since re-working my code to use the android.support.v7 libraries I'm seeing a blurred blue overlay when the SearchView is expanded.

The following is a screenshot from my Nexus 7 with the soft keyboard open.

[image]

When I close the keyboard the blurred blue image disappears but there is still a blur to the SearchView as in the image below.

[image]

I'm using a menu xml file to create the various menu items - the search item is as follows...

```
<item android:id="@+id/options_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    com.mycompany.mypackage:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    com.mycompany.mypackage:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" >
</item>
```

It does actually work in the sense I can perform searches but for the life of me I can't work out where the blurred images are coming from.

I did find this [SearchView drawables in ActionBar appear blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977952/searchview-drawables-in-actionbar-appear-blurred) but the accepted answer doesn't apply to my problem as I'm not creating the SearchView programatically.

Has anybody seen anything similar and found a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found an answer to this problem. It seems like a bug in the Build Tools. Anything from v18 onwards causes this problem and I'm now sticking with Build Tools v17.

See this question and the OP's own answer (particularly the EDIT at the end)...

[Searchview on support.v7.appcompat.library issue: default 9-patch background not renders properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288724/searchview-on-support-v7-appcompat-library-issue-default-9-patch-background-not)