# Using v7 support Action Bar means copying drawables into project?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have an open question here [Strange SearchView Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576675/strange-searchview-behaviour) which is unanswered but I suspect is related to this issue.

I started a new app project in Eclipse and simply used File -> New etc etc. I then added Action Bar support using the v7 support library as per the Android dev docs and I now have a very simple Activity as follows...

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ActionBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
    }

    // ActionBar.TabListener methods here - currently unused
}
```

I didn't do anything with styling or themes other than to set the app theme as Theme.AppCompat as instructed in the docs.

When I start the app I see this...

[image]

...but after a lot of searching and experimentation I've discovered all I had to do is manually copy abc_tab_selected.9.png from the v7-appcompat library into my project's /res/drawable-hdpi directory and I get this (which is more like I'd expect)...

[image]

So which bit of the scenario is broken? Have I missed something in the documentation (which I've gone over very many times) or do I really have to manually copy resources into my projects to get the Action Bar to style correctly? I previously used ActionBarSherlock and things pretty much worked correctly as long as I set the correct app theme - I didn't have to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really have to manually copy resources into my projects to get the Action Bar to style correctly?

Yes. The support library comes in as a jar file. And jar files don't support resources, therefore you have to copy them into your project manually.

This is what the [README file](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/README.txt) of the v7-appcompat project states:

> There is technically no source, but the src folder is necessary to
>   ensure that the build system works.  The content is actually located
>   in libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. **The accompanying resources
>   must also be included in the application.**

This is what the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) say:

> You cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as
>   you would do for a true library. Instead, you must compile the library
>   indirectly, by referencing the library in the dependent application
>   and building that application.

> I previously used ActionBarSherlock and things pretty much worked correctly

ActionBarSherlock was a complete library (or a "true library" as the docs state it) with his own resources and did not ship as a jar.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm still slightly confused though. I've basically just followed the developer.android.com guidelines to create an android-support-v7-appcompat library project and adding it as a library under Project -> Properties -> Android. That bit works without error. I assumed though that specifying Theme.AppCompat would automatically find the necessary resources. Obviously I need to look at things more closely.

Comment: I've gone through the docs again and I had actually followed all of the steps correctly. I do understand the difference between a library project and have added the v7-appcompat project in my apps Properties -> Android -> Libraries section. My problem is this bit (as you quote) **"The accompanying resources must also be included in the application."** - how do I do that? I find it hard to believe I have to go to the appcompat res folders and copy all the drawable files into my project. How do I know, for example, which drawables I need? I worked out `abc_tab_selected.9.png` as a pure guess.